# iPhone - changing the product name

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have an application on the store that has two versions: for iPad and iPhone. I have noticed now that one of the apps have a misspelled name on the **product name** field on the target info (see picture).

I wonder what would happen if I correct that. Will I have problems changing the name there?

My concerns are:

- iTC complains that the app is not the same as before
- The corrected version is not seen anymore by iOS as an upgrade to the old release. So, users are unable to update and will be forced to buy it again to continue receiving updates

Do you guys know something about this?

thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't matter. What determines the uniqueness of your app is its App ID.
The Product Name is just the name displayed on the home screen.

So as long as you don't change the App ID, you should be fine.

Comment: The product name and the name displayed on the home screen are completely separate things, however the second defaults to $(PRODUCT_NAME) when creating a new iOS project. The product name is the name of the resulting application bundle (e.g. for "My App" you get "My App.app").

Comment: @Julio - So this is my problem. If I change that, I will change the app name and perhaps iOS checks that when it upgrades.

Comment: but changing that will change the app name inside the final bundle and this is my problem. Are you sure about that?

Comment: it will be trial and error. When you update your app. Xcode verifies application first. If it goes through .. Good. if not then you might have a problem. post back after trying this.